# Vuex v-model to an object state field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a Vuex state, like this (it also has a getter, named `configs`:

```
configs: {

    1303401: {

        exampleValue: 'test'

    }

}
```

I also have an input where I v-model the `exampleValue` from the Vuex store's state:

```
<input type="text" v-model="config.exampleValue" />
```

Here is the computed property I use to return the `config`:

```
config: {

    get () {

        return this.$store.getters.configs[1303401]

    },
    set (value) {

        //this should set the configs[1303401] field with the updated exampleValue
        this.$store.dispatch('UPDATE_CONFIG', value)

    }


}
```

The input's value changes to the value of `config.exampleValue`, so the computed data is not undefined, but the Vuex state does not update.

**Also if I try to `console.log` the value in the setter, nothing appears in the console, so the setter isn't even executed**

It is probably because it is not setting the `config` computed property, but the `config.exampleValue`, but I have no idea, how to handle that.

As @asi-ple mentioned above, changing the get to return `configs[1303401].exampleValue` would work, but the problem is, that the config has more fields, and the page has more inputs, and I'd need to create a computed property for all fields this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can make some logic here if you have more than fields.

Lets say that you have

```
configs: {
    1303401: {
        exampleValue: 'test',
        exampleValue2: 'test2',
        exampleValue3: 'test3',
        ...
    } 
}
```

Than you should change template to that:

```
<input type="text" :value="config[1303401].exampleValue1" @input="update_config($event, 'exampleValue1')" />
<input type="text" :value="config[1303401].exampleValue2" @input="update_config($event, 'exampleValue2')" />
<input type="text" :value="config[1303401].exampleValue3" @input="update_config($event, 'exampleValue3')" />
```

And your methods like this

```
methods:{
    update_config($event, where){
          this.$store.commit("UPDATE_CONFIG", {value: $event.target.data, where: where})
    }
}
```

Then your mutation handler looks this

```
UPDATE_CONFIG(state, payload){
       state.configs[1303401][payload.where] = payload.value
}
```

Basically above code, your making a config data in your state which should use two-way data binding in your template. Then you are creating your inputs :value working like get methods, and @input listener is working like set methods, then update_config is committing your changes and mutation handler setting them with  right place

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you use v-model with property of the get object, and setter is not working on it.
You can just work with property only, here is how your computed property would look:

```js
config: {
    get () {
        return this.$store.getters.configs[1303401].exampleValue
    },
    set (value) {
        this.$store.dispatch('UPDATE_CONFIG', value)
    }
}
```

and template:

```html
<input type="text" v-model="config" />
```

So you will get new exampleValue value in your store action. And try to avoid using objects for getter/setter in computed properties (with forms), it has a lot of hidden traps.

Comment: Thank you, that would probably work, but I forgot to mention, that the config has other fields and the page has inputs for those too, so that way, I'd had to make a computed property for all fields of the config.

Comment: Yes, but i think you can do it much prettier without computed property. You just can take object from state to local component data and use it with inputs. For storage update you can listen to input/change events and sync data object with storage each time. So with this trick you wouldn't need a lot of computed props.